# Permutations of 20 elements, fulfilling certain rules

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations, pascal

I have to find all possible permutations of 20 elements that fulfill certain rules. For example, element 1 can never be at position 3,4,6,7,8,12 and 17, element 2 can never be at position 1,2,7,10,19 and so on. At the moment I am working with a recursive function that goes trough all possible permutations and checks if the rules are fulfilled or not. This works perfectly fine with 10 elements (10! permutations) but as you can imagine the algorithm is not usable anymore with 20 elements. Does anyone know a more efficient approach that skips the unwanted permutations? (I assume, that from the 20!=2.4E18 possible permutations only 1-2 Mio. will satisfy the rules.

This is what I am using right now (Pascal code):

```
 procedure permu(p:feldtyp; ka:bereich); 
 var
   i,h : bereich; 
 label skip;
 begin 
   if ka=teams then begin 

    //execute certain tests, skip the output part if the tests fail 
    for i:=1 to ka do if ((hh11[P[i]]+hh21[i])<>(ka-1)) or 
      ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h2[i]][1]) and ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h1[P[i]]][1])=(patterns[h2[i]][teams-1]=patterns[h2[i]][1]))) or 
      ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]<>patterns[h2[i]][1]) and ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h1[P[i]]][1])<>(patterns[h2[i]][teams-1]=patterns[h2[i]][1]))) or 
      ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]<>patterns[h2[i]][1]) and ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h1[P[i]]][1]) and (patterns[h2[i]][teams-1]=patterns[h2[i]][1]))) or 
      ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h2[i]][1]) and ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-2]=patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-3]) or (patterns[h2[i]][2]=patterns[h2[i]][3]))) or 
      ((patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-1]=patterns[h1[P[i]]][teams-2]) and (patterns[h2[i]][1]=patterns[h2[i]][2])) 
    then goto skip; 

    //all tests passed, write permutation
    // ...
    skip:
  end 
  else begin 
    for i := ka to teams do begin 
      h := P[i]; 
      P[i] := p[ka]; 
      P[ka] := h; 
      permu(p, ka+1); 
    end;
  end;
end;
```

("teams" is the constant 20 and "h1", "h2" are some arrays [1..20] defined somewhere else. Furthermore a global two dimensional array "patterns" is defined that is used to derive the rules. This array can be seen as a large 0-1 matrix with n rows and 19 columns)

Comment: Like this proably: Get a list of all allowed position for each element, Use a recursive function that places each element  at each free, allowed position and then continues recursively with the next element

Answer (score 0):

`n!` is nowhere near polynomial, 
so your execution time will 
increase drastically as `n` is larger. 
if there is some pattern on "which number(s) can/not go
to which slot(s)" then you can improve the algorithm by 
using the structure to it but your problem doesn't sound 
so.

There might be some aids to it. First of all, iterate 
on the numbers to place-- not the slots to be filled in:

for each one of the numbers `1, .., n`, use a linked 
list of slots that they can go in. Eg. number 3 can only 
go into slots 3, 16, 7, 6 --thats the linked list for n=3.

maintain a "central" array (direct access) of all `n` elements. 
Whenever you place a number, say x, to slot p, you'll 
invert the p-th element of that central array.

sort your `n` numbers so that, at the top of the 
list is the number that can go into the least number of slots, 
and at the bottom the one that can go into most number 
of slots.

start with the number at the top of the list and keep taking 
the permutations using those linked lists-- placing numbers to
unfilled slots. This gives you the solution in optimal but the 
exponential time. The problem is exponential.

You can also work a sub-optimization algorithm to run in polynomial time but not necessarily with all permutations allowed.